# React prevent focus stealing onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a simple input component, like this:

```
const InputComponent = () => {
  const inputField = React.createRef(),
        focusAtInput = () => inputField.current.focus()
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <input ref={inputField} className="inputfield">
      </input>
      <button>
        x
      </button>
      <button onClick={focusAtInput}>
        ?
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It has sliding out input field upon clicking <kbd>?</kbd> button (which triggers `<input>` element focus).

Since I don't really like "clear input" button rendered on `type="search"` attribute specified, I want to implement a custom one (<kbd>x</kbd> in my example).

The problem is clicking <kbd>x</kbd> button triggers `<input>`'s `onBlur`, which I need to avoid before cleaning input. Neither `e.stopPropagation()` nor `e.preventDefault()` didn't help. I'm guessing the reason is `onBlur` is fired **before** `onClick` has a chance to stop its propagation.

My question is: is there anything like `useCapture` parameter of `addEventListener()` or something else that could've let me prioritize event handlers or avoid stealing focus from input field on click within `<div className="wrapper">` in any other way?

Quick demo of the problem:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const InputComponent = () => {
  const inputField = React.createRef(),
        focusAtInput = () => inputField.current.focus()
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <input ref={inputField} className="inputfield">
      </input>
      <button onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        x
      </button>
      <button onClick={focusAtInput}>
        ?
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<InputComponent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.inputfield {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:none;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
.inputfield:focus {
  padding: 1px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you provide sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the visibility of your text input using React state, not focus & CSS.
This gives you a bit more flexibility on what you can do with it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const { render } = ReactDOM;

const InputComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const inputField = React.createRef();

  function toggleVisibility() {
    setIsVisible(currValue => !currValue);
  }

  function focusInput() {
    inputField.current.focus();
  }

  function openAndFocusInput() {
    toggleVisibility();
    focusInput();
  }

  function clearInput() {
    focusInput();
    setInputValue("");
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <button onClick={clearInput}>x</button>
      <button onClick={openAndFocusInput}>?</button>
      <input
        ref={inputField}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className={`inputfield ${isVisible ? "visible" : ""}`}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<InputComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

With a stylesheet like this:

```
.inputfield {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
.visible {
  padding: 1px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I have added a crude black border to highlight when the input is visible or not.

By handling the visibility through the state it means the user can click elsewhere on the page & outside the page without losing the input.
It also means when we clear the input we can apply the focus back to the input.

[You can see it working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-snowflake-zlm42)

Comment: Well that seems to be very reasonable solution - not to create the problem I was trying to cope with. Thanks, Cameron.